# Can I make multiple payments through EFTPS in one quarter?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

The reasoning behind this is pretty silly, but I was wondering if you can make more than one payment through EFTPS for the same quarter. This is the first year I am making substantial money as a contractor (my sole income). It is my first time using EFTPS. Last week while setting it up I paid $2000 as a test. This was before I had really organized all my estimates and finances.

I owe another $5000 for this quarter (which I have sitting in my bank account). Can I pay this $5000 and apply this to Q1 too without messing anything up? Or are you just supposed to pay once per quarter? The only reason I am asking is because the tax forms for end of year which you indicate quarterly payments are a bit confusing. I want to make sure the two payments do not hurt each other! Thanks.

Comment: See https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i2210#idm140434572918032 (currently for 2018, but the only change for 2019 will be the exact dates) and notice 'payments' in plural, and the second bullet item.

Answer (score 3):

Yes multiple payments can be done though EFTPS for federal. For State, I could not make multiple payments in same quarter.